# Disabled admin account on Win 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I accidentally disabled the administrator account on an install of Windows Server 2008 R2 via the net user command.

Now I cant get an elevated command prompt to re-enable the admin user, nor do any privileged operation that requires an admin password. Normally I would type in a password and click yes but there is no password field and yes is grayed out.

How can I re-enable the administrator account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try booting up in safe mode with command prompt and typing `net user administrator /active:yes`